# How to make the following corrections below in qweb pdf?

Tags: report, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

I have been working on qweb pdf for tables part with the following part:

```xml
<div class="row">
    <h3><font color="blue">Action Items:</font></h3>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>Assigned To</th>
                <!--<th class="text-center">Ref.</th>-->
                <th>Due Date</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
            <br/>
            <br/>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr t-foreach="o.action" t-as="line">
                <td><span t-field="line.act_ion"/></td>
                <td>
                    <span t-field="line.asgnd_to"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span t-field="line.due_date"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span t-field="line.Status"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and i am getting some problem like in the image like table header and table body is getting collided together in the new page [image: Image table]

Comment: Please, check if you have the [right versión of wkhtmltopdf](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/setup/install.html#deb)

Comment: yes it is installed 0.12.2.1 is the version ChesuCR

Comment: The right version is this one: `wkhtmltopdf 0.12.1 (with patched qt)`

Answer (score 0):

Create the **table** outside the **div** tag and set the following class on table: **class="table table-condensed"**